# Me aparece error 9 subindice fuera del intervalo al ejecutar una macro, alguien que sepa como solucionarlo?

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, macros

Lo que intento realizar es al pulsar un boton, que las entradas de materiales se registren en una base de datos de entradas pero al pulsar el boton me aparece error 9 subindice fuera del intervalo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a SO.

Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

También **nunca pongas código como imagen**, no ayuda para nada a reproducir el problema.

Dicho todo esto, el error que te sale significa que el subíndice especificado (el valor `BdD Entradas`) no está dentro del intervalo (el intervalo en este caso son las `Sheets` del libro activo).

En resumen, no existe la hoja `BdD Entradas` en el libro activo. Tiene toda la pinta de que te falta una letra (`bbdd`) o que te sobra una de las d (`bd`). Asegúrate que el nombre sea correcto y la próxima vez haz bien la pregunta o no recibirás ayuda.